# Draw Point on a Panning ImageView in Android

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

I have an ImageView panning by Matrix using

m.postTranslate(x, y);

command.

I found that I can get the touched x, y position based on ImageView coordinate
by using inverse() method.

But I cannot find that I can draw a point on the ImageView based on its coordinate.

Simply, I want to create a point of interest and save the position on a map (ImageView),
and draw them together preserving the position of the point.

Please see also the image below that describes what I want to do.

http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/3214/qwms.png

If anyone can give me some clue, I will be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need use a custom view for use the override metod onDraw()..thats u need for draw